# How to use an input argument as the name of a created variable?

Tags: rust, assign

So basically I would have a function that asks for two input arguments, call it name and value. Now the value x is fed into name and I want it so that a new variable called x comes up assigned with the value inside "value"

I tried it by just doing name = value but that ends up reassigning the value inside name to be value from x and not reassigning x to be value.

```
pub fn main()
{
    variable_maker(x, 20)
}

pub fn variable_maker(name, value)
{
    name = value;
}
```

Comment: Please specify your use-case. Is the `name` dynamic? What scope should the variable use? As specified, this question doesn't make much sense for Rust.

Comment: name is just a normal variable, the scope is global

Answer (score 0):

Only a macro:

```
macro_rules! variable_maker {
    ($name:ident, $expression:expr) => {
        let mut $name = $expression;
    };
}

fn main() {
    variable_maker!(x, 20);
    println!("{}", x); // 20
    x = 30;
    println!("{}", x); // 30
}
```

But what's the point?

Comment: I'm trying to store the values I get from a database into a variable. -Which I can already do but I want to also specify their names as an input argument.

Comment: You typically deserialize the data into a struct (e.g. via `serde` crate) and use the struct as in normal Rust